# Open jar from Code with cmd

Tags: java, file, cmd, path

Hey i'm trying to create a Game Launcher. I can already dowloand it from a website and it puts the files in a relative folder next to my Jar. In this folder is another jar that i want to run from my previous Code.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar "+gameFolderPath+jarLocation);
```

and my Path is:

```
private String gameFolderPath = "Game";
private String jarLocation = "/Terraria2.0/Launcher.jar";
```

It should run normally and works when i execute the jar manually in this folder or start it with cmd.
It just opens an empty Frame. There is no error log to see what's wrong. Is there any possiblity to open the jar with an open cmd ?

Edit : 
Okay now i got the real problem:
the paths in my game are all relative to my Game Folder. It uses my res/... and when i'm starting it with the

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /k \"java -jar "+gameFolderPath+jarLocation+"\"");
```

command, it uses the wrong directory as it's relation. I cant uses cd (change directory) so how can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To run within a cmd shell, try:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /k \"java -jar "+gameFolderPath+jarLocation+"\"");
```